# Can mp3 file contain a virus?

Tags: mp3, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can avi files contain a virus?](https://superuser.com/questions/445366/can-avi-files-contain-a-virus)

Can mp3 file contain an executable virus?
I mean .mp3 files only (not .mp3.exe , not an .exe renamed to .mp3 and smtg like that).

Comment: This has already been covered by a similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/445366/can-avi-files-contain-a-virus

Comment: The principle behind multimedia containers is the same. AVI, MP3, doesn't matter here. I hope the great answer to the other question explains everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it's POSSIBLE to contain a virus, but it would have to be specifically engineered to exploit a flaw in a specific media player, or in the OS itself when it generates a preview (if it does).  Since it usually just shoves the data through a player, I can't see this happening.

Comment: It wouldn't be because the file was executed, it would be because the file exploited a weakness in the software playing it.  Buffer overruns, things like that.

Comment: It means that music/video stream files can't contain a virus,  which can execute himself (while running it). Isn't it?

Comment: A virus is not always executable.

Answer (score 2):

The music player doesn't compile or run any type of executable commands on the OS. So even if a .mp3 had a virus, it can't be run/executed. So, the answer is no, it doesn't contain an executable virus (of course, if you wanted to write a music player which could also execute that would be a different matter :) but I don't think it would be popular ).